# Multiple routes for http POST request within the same API Controller in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing the backend controller  where two http post requests use two independent routes (routea and routeb) are consumed using two different actions:

For example:

http://some_domain/api/work/routea

http://some_domain/api/work/routeb

This is how the controller is configured:

```
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ControllerAndAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/work/{controller}");
```

Here would be the controller implementation:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/work")]    
public class MyController : ApiController
{
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("routea")]
        public HttpResponseMessage RouteA(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {...}

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("routeb")]
        public HttpResponseMessage RouteB()
        {...}

}
```

I cannot seem to start executing the functions. On the other hand, if two of the calls are saved in a separate controller (AController.cs and BController.cs for instance) - everything works. I need to have both routes within the same controller class. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I don't see where you're registering your attribute routes.

Comment: If the RouteB is commented, then the RouteA works correctly, they used to be in separate controller classes and that worked.

Comment: I think it may be due to the method signature. It should work if you make one of the route method to receive a parameter (For example... a class object / string / int or whatever)....

Comment: Again, where are you calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`?

Comment: MapHttpAttributeRoutes is called at Startup.cs, just before app.UseWebApi(config);

Comment: Please include your full route registration in the question.

Comment: I used it before in two separate controllers. By commenting out block of the controller with RouteB in the sample shown above, the other route works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a such construction to define base route configuration then you can use your "routea" and "routeb" as controller's names only .

```
routeTemplate: "api/work/{controller}");
```

try this instead:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Everything should be fine in this case with your controller's implementation.